# Add line break after <p> tag using Javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, line

I need a script that puts a line break after the "p" tag.
I would do it manually in the html but the paragraphs are dynamically added to the site by tumblr.

Basically my code is :

```
 <div class="title"><a>{Caption}</a></div>
```

Where it says caption tumblr replaces with a real caption and i need to add line breaks between the "p" tags using javascript/jquery.

Comment: Why would you need a line break after a `<p>` element? Can't you just style it with CSS?

Comment: @user2736012 That's what I was wondering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.title a p').after( '<br />' );
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Cfhsx/)

Comment: *"between the "p" tags"* not sure if he means inside or between the first and second paragraph if there are two, or what.

Comment: "I need a script that puts a line break after the "p" tag"

Comment: That line is ambiguous, `<p>is this inbetween the p</p>` or `<p></p>is this inbetween the p tags</p>`, id say up for interpretation

Comment: He said it two different ways in his question, haha.

Comment: @KevinB -  Without seeing a code example of what the inserted markup looks like, and some clarification from the OP what "between" really is, I'm guessing it's this ?

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine. Most likely after is what he intended.

Comment: @KevinB I meant between the <p></p>, sorry

Answer (score 2):

CSS margin would be good here.

```
.title p {margin-bottom:10px}
```